# How do you edit the color of a label in main class from a different class?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm a beginner java programmer and I'm making a small app where I can enter my school marks and see my total score. I have 2 classes in total (1 for javafx layout and 1 for my Methods), and I'm trying to change the color of a label (.setTextFill) which is in the main class with a method in the methods class.

I have tried making an object of the main class but this gives an error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception{
  totalPercent = new Label(Methods.getTotalPercent());
  totalPercent.setTextFill(Color.web("#4ecf17"));
}

//next code is in a different class
public void setPercentColor(){
    if(percent <  50){
        totalPercent.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0000"));
    }else if(percent >=  50 && percent <  60){
        totalPercent.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff7700"));
    }else if (percent >=  60 && percent <  100){
        totalPercent.setTextFill(Color.web("#59ff00"));
    }else{
        totalPercent.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
    }
}
```

So basically I don't know how to change the color from the label 'totalPercent' with a method that's located in a different class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of your classes is not done well considering the `setPercentColor` method: It controls the details of the representation of some view managed by another class.

I recommend redesigning `Methods` to provide a property and letting the other class decide on what to do with this value.

In this case you could add a `ReadOnlyIntegerProperty percent` instead of using a field. This way the other class can use bindings/listeners to update the view and the only thing `Methods` needs to worry about is updating the property.

#### In `Methods`

```
// private int percent;
private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper percent = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();

public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty percentProperty() {
    return percent.getReadOnlyProperty();
}

public int getPercent() {
    return percent.get();
}

...
// percent = i
percent.set(i); // replace assinment to int field with setting the property
```

#### Other class

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception{
    totalPercent = new Label();

    totalPercent.textProperty().bind(Methods.percentProperty().asString());

    final Color color560 = Color.web("#ff7700");
    final Color color100 = Color.web("#59ff00");
    totalPercent.textFillProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
              int percent = Methods.getPercent();
              if(percent <  50) {
                  return Color.RED;
              } else if(percent < 60) {
                  return color60;
              }else if (percent < 100){
                  return color100;
              } else {
                  return Color.BLACK;
              }
          }, Methods.percentProperty()));
}
```

BTW: I recommend choosing a more meaningful name for the `Methods` class: Most classes contain method implementations, so the name contains basically no valuable info to someone reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I'd suggest passing the `totalPercent` Label to the new class so that you can modify it. As an example,

```
public class FirstClass {
    Label totalPercent;
    SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass();

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      totalPercent = new Label(Methods.getTotalPercent());
      totalPercent.setTextFill(Color.web("#4ecf17"));
      secondClass.setTotalPercent(totalPercent);
    }
}

public class SecondClass {
    Label totalPercent;

    //next code is in a different class
    public void setPercentColor() {
        if(percent <  50){
            totalPercent.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0000"));
        }else if(percent >=  50 && percent <  60){
            totalPercent.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff7700"));
        }else if (percent >=  60 && percent <  100){
            totalPercent.setTextFill(Color.web("#59ff00"));
        }else{
            totalPercent.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        }
    }

    public void setTotalPercent(Label totalPercent) {
        this.totalPercent = totalPercent;
    }
}
```

Lastly, as just an opinion of my own. I'd suggest naming your variables a little more descriptively. As an example, you name your Label variable `totalPercent`, but I'd suggest `totalPercentLabel`. I'd also suggest `setPercentColor()` to be something like `setTotalPercentLabelColor()`. It's a little more descriptive and when I look at that method alone it's immediately clear what's going on. The method is descriptive, and I know what you're doing to `totalPercentLabel`. Right now I'm not sure what `setPercentColor()` is doing and I'm not sure what object the `totalPercent` is representing unless I look at the other parts of your code.

Comment: I have implemented this code and it works perfectly. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Since you're new on StackOverflow, don't forget to accept an answer :)